# Tracy-Widom distribution - Phase transitions - catastrophe/chaos - 'surface-fit'/'curve-fit' software

Tags: references, goodness-of-fit

Is there an algorithm to determine the fit of a sample set of data to a saddle curve?

I'd like to know the variance from the closest fit the sample has to:
\begin{align}
z &= x^3 - 3xy^2  \\
z &= x^2 - y^2
\end{align}
and

$$\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} - \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$$

Any suggestions as to where to look?

Comment: Migrating at OP's request.